# Searching for multiple keywords in the same file within bigger project in Sublime Text 3

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I would like to search a whole project for files that have both `ABCKeyword` and `XYZKeyword` in the same file. Is this possible?

When I search a whole project with regex `(ABCKeyword|XYZKeyword)`, it returns files that have one or the other but not necessarily both.

Answer (score 1):

You can use positive look-aheads:

```
(?s)^(?=.*\bABCKeyword\b)(?=.*\bXYZKeyword\b)
```

Only the text that has both will be matched.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iU1dP5/2)

`(?s)` makes the `.` to match a newline symbol. `(?=.*...)` look-aheads check, but do not consume characters, thus only asseting if there is `ABCKeyword` or `XYZKeyword` further in the text. The `\b` word boundaries make sure we only match full words (if you need to match them partially, inside longer words, remove `\b`s).